# Experience Analytics Graphs are not loading in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics

We are working on Sitecore 9.3 with SXA and having a scaled setup, 2 CMs, 4 CDs,1 Xconnect server, 1 Solr server, and initially, there were some errors on the Experience analytics tab, and that we fixed by providing app pool, IIS_IUSRS, Network Service, Local Service permission to the certificates and webroot. So for now we don't see any error on the Experience Analytics tabs but still can't see the graphs loading, and checked the logs were clean in the CM and CD servers but there was an error in the Xconnect logs.

```
2021-03-09 11:01:45.923 -06:00 [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.SetFacetOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Facet]: Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException: Operation #1, ReferenceNotFound, Contact, Classification
2021-03-09 11:01:45.923 -06:00 [Error] ["XdbContextLoggingPlugin"] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception
Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.EntityOperationException: Operation #0, AlreadyExists, Contact
2021-03-09 11:01:45.923 -06:00 [Error] ["XdbContextLoggingPlugin"] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception
Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException: Operation #1, ReferenceNotFound, Contact, Classification
```

When searched this error on google, we found that this was fixed in the Sitecore 9.2 version and later.
I found some blogs suggesting rebuilding the Xdb and all other indexes, deploy marketing strategies, deleting Xdb cores, create again and rebuild, I tried everything but had no luck.

[image]

The changes I made -

***Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config In CD server***

`<setting name="Analytics.ClusterName" value="www.domainname.com" />`

`<setting name="Analytics.HostName" value="sitecorecm.dev.local" />`

***Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config In CM server***

`<setting name="Analytics.ClusterName" value="" />`

`<setting name="Analytics.HostName" value="" />`

The last step I did was to disable the ***Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Client.config*** file on each server.

Any thoughts would be appreciable. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Try also the following steps:

- Rebuild the indexes.
- Rebuild the links databases.
- Rebuild the xDB index (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuilding-the-xdb-search-index.html)
- Deploy the marketing definitions again.
- Empty the *App_Data/Submit Queue* folder from the CD boxes.
- Double check that all certificates are well configured on each box.
- Make also sure you have the VisitorIdentification in your main layout.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1)restart each app pool and browse each application  cm, cd, xconnect...

2)after each restart and browsing the application verify the logs both in application and Jobs.

this should give you the probable issue.