# Experience analytics graph is not loading in Sitecore 10.2

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-analytics

We were working on Sitecore 10.2 upgrade.

We are not able to see the experience graph, but we can see the graph in our lower environment(UAT) with same database.

Can you help us to find the troubleshooting steps?

Comment: can you see some errors there?

Comment: Check these - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28052/experience-analytics-graphs-are-not-loading-in-sitecore-9-3
https://tothecore.sk/2018/07/11/experience-analytics-graphs-in-sitecore-9-not-showing-because-of-the-listcontrol-list-linechart-graph-cannot-be-displayed-due-to-a-server-error-exception/

Comment: What is your original Sitecore version? See the detailed Upgrade Guide here: https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/93CC3A931DB7459AAC38BA111E0DD16D.ashx?date=20220929T145510 for additional steps you have to undertake for your xDB configuration and data during the upgrade depending on your current version

Comment: I don't see any errors in that dashboard and CM server logs. We can see the graph in our lower environment by using the upgraded reporting database.

I have already tried the steps given in those link, which suggested by sitecore team in the ticket created with them.

Comment: Try to turn on Debug level logging on your CM/CD and then check logs. Some of the analytics calls can be seen only like that. Is it hosted on PaaS or VM? Can you check logs for Reporting role? Are all certificates correct? https://himynameistim.com/blog/debugging-sitecore-9-analytics-issues

Comment: Check the logs of your cd and all the xdb instances.  Seen this issue before related to config issues (thumbprints and such) which caused no data in the xdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some duplicate items in our Sitecore content tree(Master DB) inside experience analytics folder. We have cleaned up and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

A fact that you don't see any errors suggests that this is likely to be a data problem.

I would recommend to rebuild the Reporting database and xDB search index.

The Reporting DB rebuild is a semi-automated process and can be initiated by the pre-built script on CM instance, just open the below link on your CM:

```
      {your_cm_site_domain}/sitecore/admin/RebuildReportingDB.aspx
```

Read more [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-platform/rebuild-the-reporting-database.html).

Once the Reporting DB has been successfully rebuilt you need to manually trigger the rebuild of the xDB search index depending on your search provider. See [this article](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-platform/rebuild-the-xdb-index-in-solr.html) about how to rebuild the xDB index in Solr.

Comment: Thanks @Kate. We already rebuilt reporting DB.